# Wifi with an old usb wifi key. Network icon ok, but no connection (either ethernet)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ethernet, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to connect my computer with a old wifi usb key (with ubuntu 16.04).
I've the connection, the wifi icon is ok, but when I'm using a web browser : no connection.

I've post on a french ubuntu forumm, [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2035248). So the commands I've launch are, with wificheck, [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22030490#p22030490).
And, I've remove WPA/WPA2 method to keep only one "WPA2", [here](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22030594#p22030594), with the web administration panel on my internet box.

I'm on DHCP, and I think this service is ok :

```
~$ sudo nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -e enp5s0

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-06 17:30 CET
Pre-scan script results:
| broadcast-dhcp-discover: 
|   Response 1 of 1: 
|     IP Offered: 192.168.1.11
|     DHCP Message Type: DHCPOFFER
|     Server Identifier: 192.168.1.254
|     IP Address Lease Time: 2m00s
|     Renewal Time Value: 1m00s
|     Rebinding Time Value: 1m45s
|     Broadcast Address: 192.168.1.255
|     Hostname: Host-001
|     Interface MTU: 1500
|     Domain Name Server: 192.168.1.254
|     Domain Name: lan
|     Router: 192.168.1.254
|_    Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.78 seconds
```

and :

```
~$ cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases 
lease {
  interface "vboxnet0";
  fixed-address 192.168.56.101;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 1200;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.56.100;
  renew 4 2019/01/03 19:28:19;
  rebind 4 2019/01/03 19:37:21;
  expire 4 2019/01/03 19:39:51;
}
lease {
  interface "wlx0018e771164b";
  fixed-address 192.168.1.56;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.254;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.254;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.254;
  option interface-mtu 1500;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 43200;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 75600;
  option host-name "spectre";
  option domain-name "lan";
  renew 4 2019/01/03 23:02:43;
  rebind 5 2019/01/04 10:27:24;
  expire 5 2019/01/04 13:27:24;
}
```

And, when I plug an ethernet cable (the box see the computer in the administration panel) but, no connection :(

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I change the /etc/resolv.conf file : comment/change the 'NameServer' directive.

And now, it's ok :)